# Mozilla firefox vs Internet Explorer - html

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox

I have a problem because I am using a Dropdown box on a page and this is only appearing correctly in Mozilla Firefox.

The code is as follows:

```
    <label for="liste">Add to list (choose list) : </label>
    <select  name="liste" id="liste" action="">

    <option value="OKK" id="Option1">Hello</option>
</select>
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong please?

C

I'm using IE 7 and IE 8 and both are appearing wrong. The code previous to this displays a popup and this is displaying correctly for each browser and version but IE wont display the dropdown

Comment: It's not asp.net for a start. Is it displaying at all?

Comment: What version of each of the browsers are you using?  Does your code check out here using the w3c validator? http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Do you have a closing </select>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the action from your select element. This should go in your form tag.

```
<label for="liste">Add to list (choose list) :</label>
<select name="liste" id="liste">
  <option value="OKK">Hello</option>
</select>
```

I would also check if your html is w3c valid.

Answer (score 0):

action is not html select property.
I not see the close tag for select, the code should be like this

```
<label for="liste">Add to list (choose list) :</label>
<select name="liste" id="liste">
  <option value="OKK">Hello</option>
</select>
```